Trace of the Kronecker product of a matrice and its transpose
For some matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, what is the trace of the Kronecker product of a matrix and its transpose, i.e., $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes A^{\top})$?
Now I need to calculate the trace $\operatorname{tr}[\{C(B\otimes u)\}\otimes \{(u^{\top}\otimes B)C\}]$, where $B,C$ are symmetric matrices, $u$ is a column vector.
I want to reformulate the above trace as some quantity related to the Frobenius norm of some matrix. The reason why I am considering this problem is that the kronecker product within the trace shares some similar form with $A\otimes A^{\top}$, and I want to know if $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes A^{\top})$ can be expressed as some Frobenius norm based quantity.

@QiaochuYuan Padding with zeros doesn't lead to the right answer. As an example, consider the case where $A$ is either a row vector or a column vector. The trace comes out to the sum of the squares of the entries, but setting things up with matrix padding just gives you a single entry squared.

It might be helpful to start with the case that $A$ has rank 1. If $A = uv^\top$, we end up with
$$
\operatorname{tr}((uv^\top) \otimes (uv^\top)^\top) = (u \otimes v)^\top (v \otimes u)
$$

The following reframing might be helpful. The trace can be expressed as
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}(A \otimes A^T) &=
\text{Tr}([A \otimes I_n][I_n \otimes A]^\top ).
\end{align}
In other words, we are taking the Frobenius inner product (i.e. the matrix "dot-product") of $A \otimes I_n$ and $I_n \otimes A$.

Notably,
$$
I_n \otimes A = \pmatrix{A \ & \ddots \ && A}, \quad A \otimes I_n = \pmatrix{a_{11}I_n & \cdots & a_{1n}I_n\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\
a_{m1}I_n & \cdots & a_{mn}I_n}.
$$
These block matrices hae the same column-partitioning, but different row-partitionings

Let’s look at an example. The diagonal elements of $\pmatrix{a&d\ b&e\ c&f}\otimes\pmatrix{a&b&c\ d&e&f}$ are $aa,ae,bc,ed,fb,ff$.

@user1551 Thanks for your comments. Your and Qiaochu's answers have made me realize that this problem may not be a natural one. I have added some explanations about why I am considering this problem.

@BenGrossmann Thanks for your comments. I have added some explanations about why I am considering this problem. I think your comments have solved one of my doubts, that is $tr(A\otimes A^{\top})$ is actually the Frobenius product of $I_{n}\otimes A$ and $A\otimes I_{n}$.

@user1551 Actually the orginal question is that calculate the trace $tr(A\otimes \tilde{A})$, where $A = C(B\otimes u)$ and $\tilde{A} = (u^{\top}\otimes B)C$. I want to know if this trace can be expressed as some quantity of Frobenius norm form, though these two traces are not exactly the same ($A^{\top}\neq \tilde{A}$, but they share some similar form).

You are right, $A^T=(B\otimes u^T)C\ne\tilde{A}=(u^T\otimes B)C$, but that is not my point. What I mean is, given any $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $A_1\otimes A_2^T$ usually represents a linear map $\mathbb R^{m\times n}\ni X\mapsto A_2^TXA_1^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ between two different vector spaces (of the same dimension). Since this is not an endomorphism, it is not natural to take the trace of its matrix representation. The inner structures of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are immaterial. I just have a hard time to see why the trace of $A_1\otimes A_2^T$ is a meaningful quantity.

Without $C$ (or when $C=I$),
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left((B\otimes u)\otimes(u^T\otimes B)\right)
=\operatorname{tr}\left(B\otimes (u\otimes u^T)\otimes B\right)
=\operatorname{tr}(B)\operatorname{tr}(u\otimes u^T)\operatorname{tr}(B)
=\operatorname{tr}(B)^2|u|_2^2.
$$
With a general symmetric $C$, I don’t expect any nice answer.

My apologies for making several incorrect statements in a row. The situation here is more complicated than I expected, for the following reason.
Abstractly we can think of $A$ as the matrix of a linear operator $T : H_1 \to H_2$ between two finite-dimensional real Hilbert spaces (wrt some orthonormal bases), and its transpose as the the matrix of the adjoint $T^{\dagger} : H_2 \to H_1$ (wrt the same orthonormal bases). Then the Kronecker product is the matrix of the tensor product
$$T \otimes T^{\dagger} : H_1 \otimes H_2 \to H_2 \otimes H_1.$$
So there's a subtlety here: we can't quite take the trace of this linear operator, because its source and target aren't quite the same vector space. This is disguised by working in coordinates with the Kronecker product, where the source and target both look like $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. But one of them is $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ and the other one is $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$, so to speak.
We can produce an operator we can take the trace of by composing with the swap isomorphism
$$H_2 \otimes H_1 \ni v \otimes u \mapsto u \otimes v \in H_1 \otimes H_2$$
and if we do that then using the SVD of $T$ produces an answer of $(\sum \sigma_i)^2$, where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $T$. But this potentially scrambles which elements of $A \otimes A^T$ are considered the diagonal ones, so I don't think this ends up being the same as $\text{tr}(A \otimes A^T)$.
For example, if $m = n$ then $A$ and $A^T$ are both square matrices, and in this case the trace is multiplicative with respect to Kronecker product, so we get that
$$\text{tr}(A \otimes A^T) = \text{tr}(A) \text{tr}(A^T) = \text{tr}(A)^2 = (\sum \lambda_i)^2$$
is now the square of the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$, rather than the singular values. These won't agree in general if $A$ is not normal, e.g. if $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$, or even if $A$ is normal but some of its eigenvalues are negative or complex.
So it looks to me like this is not a "natural" question, in the sense that you're taking the trace of a matrix in a way that doesn't naturally correspond to taking the trace of a linear operator.

@Ben: whoops. I don't really understand what's going on anymore but I've edited with my current understanding.

With the swap operator invoked in this way, you can produce a formula for the trace involving the commutation matrix, though I'm not sure how "satisfying" that answer would be.
